# Keypress event not detetcting Ctrl+V event in CHrome borwser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**AngularJS**

```
element.bind("keypress", function() {
    if(attrs.id == 'headEdit' && scope.selectedTab.facebook){
        return element.text().length <= 50;
    }
});
```

Here I can set maximum text length as 50. But when paste some text(cntrl+V) into this box, the text exceeds maximumum length. This problem only in Chrome browser.

Comment: You could simply return the first 50 character of your element text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414916/display-only-10-characters-of-a-long-string

Answer (score 1):

Something Like

```
element.bind("keypress", function() {
if(attrs.id == 'headEdit' && scope.selectedTab.facebook){
   // return element.text().length <= 50; 
    return    element.val(elem.val().substr(0, 50));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

probably it's better to use `ng-change`?

```
<input ng-model="someField" ng-change="validate()">
```

to keep it Angular way

or even better to use [ng-paste](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPaste)

```
<input ng-paste="validate">
```