# Limit characters displayed in span

Tags: html, css

Is there some sort of way within HTML or CSS to limit the characters displayed with a span? I use a repeater that displays these info boxes and I want to limit the characters to the first 20 characters and if the input has more, then just concatenate? The box is like image shown:

[image]

My code for this is:

```
<span class="claimedRight" maxlength="20">{{ item.provider }}</span>
```

Comment: `maxlength` is an input element attribute. You can set a width for the item and use `text-overflow: ellipsis` in CSS. Limiting characters is not possible with CSS since it cannot work with text nodes.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Here's an example of using text-overflow:

```css
.text {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Hello world this is a long sentence</span>
```

Comment: Would add that when using this technique it's a good idea to set your width to `em` units so that the amount of text that fits in your containers scales with the font size.

Comment: This is not the best answer.  OP should use `ch` instead of `px`, to approximate the 20 character max they want;  and the `display` property should be `inline-block` if we're working with a `span`, else OP would have specified a `div`.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the CSS property `max-width` and use it with `ch` unit.
And, as this is a `<span>`, use a `display: inline-block;` (or block).

Here is an example:

```
<span style="
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 13ch;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</span>
```

Which outputs:

```
Lorem ipsum...
```

```html
<span style="
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 13ch;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks , `max-width: 13ch` and `display:inline-block ` allow me to concatenate text one by one with fixed size.

Answer (score 8):

You can use css `ellipsis;` but you have to give fixed width and `overflow:hidden:` to that element.

```html
<span style="display:block;text-overflow: ellipsis;width: 200px;overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
 </span>
```

Comment: how can I do it without display block?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with jQuery :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.claimedRight').each(function (f) {

      var newstr = $(this).text().substring(0,20);
      $(this).text(newstr);

    });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script         src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="claimedRight" maxlength="20">Hello this is the first test string. 
    </span><br>
    <span class="claimedRight" maxlength="20">Hello this is the second test string. 
    </span>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`max-length` is used for `input` elements. Use `text-overflow` property of CSS.

```
.claimedRight {
    display:block; width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use js:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
   { $(".class-span").each(function(i){
        var len=$(this).text().trim().length;
        if(len>100)
        {
            $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,100)+'...');
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: If you can use css instead of js, go for css.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sort of.

You can explicitly size a container using units relative to font-size:

- 1em = 'the horizontal width of the letter m'
- 1ex = 'the vertical height of the letter x'
- 1ch = 'the horizontal width of the number 0'

In addition you can use a few CSS properties such as `overflow:hidden;` `white-space:nowrap;` `text-overflow:ellipsis;` to help limit the number as well.

Comment: «em = 'the horizontal width of the letter m'» are you sure? It doesn't seem to be the case.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems

Comment: Thanks for catching this, the ems were the only thing right about this post. I'll edit it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <span class="textlimit">4.3471230472308468902346802364373479037 
      </span><br>
      <span class="textlimit">Hello this is the second test string. 
      </span>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         
         $('.textlimit').each(function (f) {
         
             var newstr = $(this).text().substring(0,5);
             $(this).text(newstr);
         
           });
         })
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The user want with HTML or CSS.