# Cutting text and put ... at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good Morning.

I have a textarea and when I type in anything it display the written stuff in an span container. And I want that when I have typed in a number of characters (156 characters) that it  display ... in the span container and nothing else. How can I do this?

**This is my span container**

```
<span class="metadescription"> </span>
```

And 
**This my text area**.

```
<textarea class="checklength" data-limit="156" data-class=".metadescription" type="text" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Leon, you are actually meant to have made an attempt to do this yourself.  And if you get stuck, then come to SO with a specific problem relating to the code.  As it stands, your question can have many answers and therefore is too broad, hence off topic for SO

Comment: My problem is that i'm a javascript and jquery noob.

Comment: Well you need to do some research then, there are plenty of example on the internet if you search for them - as it says at the beginning of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "search and research" - don't just expect us to do the work for you, this is not a code writing service

Comment: That was not my intention. It was just a Question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not 100% sure what you asked for but was this anything close to what you would like?

```js
$('.checklength').on('keyup',function() {
  var limit = $(this).data("limit");
  if($(this).val().length > limit) {
  $(".metadescription").html($(this).val().substring(0,limit) + "...")
  }else{
  $(".metadescription").html($(this).val())
  }
})
```

```css
span{width: 199px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="checklength" data-limit="156" data-class=".metadescription" type="text" ></textarea>
<br><span class="metadescription"> </span>
```

Comment: Yes it works thank you :D

Comment: Happy to hear that it works as you want, please remember to upvote or mark as answer so others know it works

Answer (score -1):

you could try it with css, see this answer:
[Limit characters displayed in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718245/limit-characters-displayed-in-span) 
Seems like what you are looking for to me.