# With the use of Jquery, how to target CSS selectors with the exception of one class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is an example of the HTML:

```html
<div class="DataBox">
  <div class="diagram">
    <h3 class="dataNumber">
      Artificial intelligence is the intelligence 
        of machines or software, as opposed to the 
        intelligence of humans or animals.
      <span class="subDataTitle">
        AI augments human intelligence with rich analytics
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to truncate the text underneath the `.dataNumber` to a certain character amount, but I don't want to truncate any of the text in `subDataTitle`.

With how the HTML is structured, how would I write the code so that I'm only applying truncating logic to the text underneath `dataNumber` but not to the text in `subDataTitle` .

This is how I approached it using the `:not`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.DataBox .diagram .dataNumber:not(.DataBox .diagram .dataNumber.subDataTitle)')
  .each(function (index, value) {
    var dataLength = $(this).text().length;
    if (dataLength > 8) {
      $(this).html($(this).html().substring(0, 12) + ' ...');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `:not()` expression is that you use `.dataNumber.subDataTitle`, which expects the `subDataTitle` class to be in the same element as `.dataNumber` to exclude it. But you don't want to operate on `.dataNumber` itself, you want to select its descendants.

However, you can't easily operate on the text directly in the `h3` separately from the `span` nested below it. The selector matches the whole `h3` element.

You should put each of the descendants in their own `<span>` tags, so you can target them directly. Then you can use `:not()` to exclude `.subDataTitle`.

You can also use a function argument to `.text()` or `.html()` instead of `.each()`.

```js
$('.DataBox .diagram .dataNumber >*:not(.subDataTitle)').text(function(index, text) {
  var dataLength = text.length;
  if (dataLength > 8) {
    return text.substring(0, 12) + ' ...';
  } else {
    return text;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DataBox">
  <div class="diagram">
    <h3 class="dataNumber">
      <span>Artificial intelligence is the intelligence of machines or software, as opposed to the intelligence of humans or animals.</span>
      <span class="subDataTitle">AI augments human intelligence with rich analytics</span>
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of actually changing the text with JavaScript, you might consider using a CSS solution like [Limit characters displayed in span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718245/limit-characters-displayed-in-span)